# Free Screen Recording Software for Windows like Camtasia Studio 8?

Tags: windows, gratis, video-editing, screen-recording

I require screen recording software to stream video.

I was utilizing [Camtasia Studio 8](https://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html). This product is totally incredible: extraordinary video quality and record size, and it has a brilliant implicit editorial manager. What's more, it's lightweight!
Shockingly, it's not free. (

I discovered [ActivePresenter](https://atomisystems.com/activepresenter/free-edition/). Great programming, the video quality is great, but I cannot find a way to export to MP3 and sound related file.

I attempted a lot of them:

- [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/): Bugs the poo out of my PC.
- [HyperCam](http://de.hyperionics.com/hc/index.asp): Heavy CPU utilization and low FPS yield recordings.
- Frozen yogurt Screen Recorder: Low quality video yield.
- [OpenBroadcaster](https://obsproject.com/): Heavy CPU use. Makes the video/stream shade. Attempted distinctive settings.

Neither of them worked for me. For reasons like overwhelming CPU utilization, low quality/fps video yield, don't recording framework sound, enormous documents yield, makes the livestream on the program shade, and so on.

Also, some I didn't even try in the wake of seeing the interface. I've tried a great deal of them with "straightforward" interface too, yet once more, to uninstall it directly after.

I have a low end scratch pad with a Pentium N3520 and 4GB of RAM. The Camtasia Studio 8 is magnifient on this machine, yet the cost... :(

Do you folks have any recommendation?

Comment: Have you tried Jing (https://www.techsmith.com/jing.html) before? It is free and allows screen recording.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. It might help if you could point out how Camtasia works: what features do you need?

Comment: If you just want to extract the sound out to mp3, then use activepresenter and use videolan client to extract the audio.

Comment: What is your affiliation with this product?

Comment: @MinhTandecoder you are a developer for ActivePresenter. So how comes you just "discovered" it? You're promoting it with each of your answers without mentioning your affiliation. So do you mean your question here honestly, or is this another try to draw attention to your product?

Comment: Why is it "shocking" to you that an "incredible" product is not "free"? Also, have you seen the [pricing](https://atomisystems.com/pricing/) of the alternative you discovered ... looking at the comparison table, there are quite a few other "incredible" features of that alternative that are ... not free either. Or am I missing something?